# About removing an item from a list with a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Let's say we try to remove all elements of a list with the following code:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in a:
    a.remove(i)
```

Of course this is not "permitted" and will fail. On the other hand we could do:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in list(a):
    a.remove(i)
```

and this *would* work. So, I have two questions:

1. Why is the second method working?
2. Is the second method acceptable and should be used?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I will go with the approach of firstly finding out the index that you want to delete and then in second loop just delete those indexes because now you will be iterating over those indexes that need to be deleted and inside the loop you can simple do `del a[index]` this will be safe method

Comment: For the record, you can empty out a list by calling `.clear()` on it. No need for a loop.

Comment: By the way, if you want to remove all elements, there's no need to loop over anything, you can simply use `del a[:]` -- `del a[i]` would remove the `i`th element from the list, `del a[start:stop]` deletes all elements from `start` to `stop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second code works because a new list is created with `list(a)`. You then iterate through the new list and remove items from the original list.

The second code is acceptable in the sense that you are not iterating through the same list you are modifying.

Answer (score 1):

You can get some sense about the process by adding prints to your code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in a:
    print('Deleting: {}'.format(i))
    a.remove(i)
print(a)
```

In your first sample, the loop starts with deleting `1`, and then moving on to the second element in the list. However, since you deleted `1`, the next element in terms of the loop is the second element in the list, which is now `3` (`2` is the first now) - so the loop deletes `3`. And then it wants to delete the third element, but no such element any more.

In the second sample, `list(a)` actually creates a new instance of a list (with the same elements as `a`), so what you actually do is to iterate over the elements of this new list, and delete the corresponding elements in original `a`. Since both lists hold the same elements - all the elements in `a` are being deleted.

About what your second question about what is accepted - it all depends what you'd like to achieve.